# Working with arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a simple way to get the total of all items in a PHP array?

Also, how can I output the contents of an array for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is array_sum http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

array_sum — Calculate the sum of values in an array

To output the contents of an array use [`var_dump`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`print_r`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). e.g

```
$myarr = array(1,5,2,7,6);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myarr);
echo "</pre>";

echo "The Sum of my array is ".array_sum($myarr);

// Output

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 6
)

The Sum of my array is 21
```

Comment: Or use var_dump() instead of print_r()

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/array_sum

PHP has a great documentation site, be sure to reference it.

Comment: PHP has a *ton* of array-specific (and string-specific) functions, and it's a good idea to read over the options on php.net any time you're trying to do something funky with either of them.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need it for debugging `var_dump($variable);` is good for seeing what everything's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you mean the total number of items or the total of all items (in the case of numeric values)...

- To get the number of items in an array use `count()`
- To get the sum of all numbers use `array_sum()`

[count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) [array_sum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)